# Qual o ciclo de vida de uma requisição HTTP nos padrões MVC?

Tags: mvc

Eu desenvolvo em ASP.NET MVC5 já faz 1 ano e 2 meses, e até hoje não consegui entender direito quem chama quem.
Pesquisando mais, encontrei [essa resposta](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/175952) que diz(em tradução livre):

> Ciclo de vida de uma requisição HTTP:
>
> O usuário faz a requisição HTTP;
>
> O controller intercepta;
>
> O controller chama o serviço apropriado;
>
> O serviço chama o DAO apropriado que retorna algum dado persistente(por exemplo);
>
> O serviço trata o dado e retorna para o controller;
>
> O controller guarda os dados no model e chama a view;
>
> A view popula com os dados do model e returna a requisição HTTP.

O que seria esse **serviço** ? Atualmente eu chamo classes estáticas que fazem o processamento, guarda e recupera dados do banco, isso seria a mesma coisa que esses serviços?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Serviço é uma das 3 camadas da aplicação

A pergunta que você postou como referência para a sua pergunta, chama de "serviço" a camada intermediária da aplicação. Essa camada intermediária é descrita dentro de uma arquitetura de 3 camadas (dados, serviços, apresentação), onde a camada de serviço teria o código que faz acesso à camada de dados, aplica regras de negócio e retorna para a camada de apresentação exibir ao usuário.

A resposta coloca o MVC dentro da camada de apresentação. A chamada feita ao controller, passa à camada de serviço que chama a camada de dados (DAO), faz um tratamento com esses dados e aplica regras de negócio, e retorna para continuar e ser direcionada para a View, onde seria formatada (HTML) para apresentação ao usuário.

Essa separação de camadas é uma separação lógica dentro do sistema, porém é possível ter uma implementação onde a camada de serviço tivesse que ser acessada através de uma chamada a uma API que reside em outra máquina e após o retorno enviar os dados recebidos para a View.